# Campos Personalizados: Não está aparecendo na página do site!

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um a página com campos personalizados, até ai tudo bem, mas quando salvo no site não aparece o campo, que seria um BLOCO.

[image: A página com os campos personalizados]

Usei o código `<?php the_meta(); ?>` e apareceu assim, bagunçado:

[image: conteudo bagunçado]

Não sei o que fazer!
Esse site foi desenvolvido por outro profissional, estou tentando fazer uma mudança, que ao meu ver era simples...:(

Na home do site esse mesmo conteúdo aparece em blocos, um do lado do outro.

Já olhei o arquivo PHP, já olhei tudo, e não consigo fazer o conteúdo carregar com a formatação correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigão use essa function, coloque ela em qualquer luga no functions.php

```
function pegar_campo( $field_name, $post_id = false ) {

$value = get_post_meta($post_id, $field_name);

if( is_array($value) )
{
    $value = @implode(', ',$value);
}

return $value; }
```

dai fica mais facil de recuperar no post, coloque:

```
<?php echo pegar_campo('campo', $post->ID); ?>
```

Eu uso essa function em meus temas, dê uma testada

Comment: Eu coloco assim então? <?php echo get_the_meta('bloco', $post->3764); ?>

Comment: Amigão, alterei a resposta, dê uma olhada, vai ficar mais simples para vossa pessoa!

Comment: O grupo que criei no plugin é http://ramosdesign.com.br/grupo.jpg e na página de edição aparece assim: http://ramosdesign.com.br/007.jpg são na verdade dois blocos, um parceiros que deveria ficar assim: http://ramosdesign.com.br/parceiros.jpg e outro o que fazemos que seria assim: http://ramosdesign.com.br/bloco2.jpg

Comment: No seu erro ele mostrou os campos personalizados que você tem, aqui seguem eles:
subtitle, banner, oquefazemos_0_imagem, oquefazemos_0_titulo, oquefazemos_0_resumo, oquefazemos_0_conteudo

Se você quise o titulo por ex você usa:

<?php echo pegar_campo('subtitle', $post-ID); ?>

use a function que te mandei ai, ela vai ser uma ajuda muito forte pra você!

Comment: Poxa Rafael, valeu pela força! Já começou a aparecer o conteúdo. Não teria essa função para chamar o grupo inteiro?

Comment: se quiser chamar o grupo inteiro use cada codigo para puxar cada coisa, ficaria assim:

<?php echo pegar_campo('subtitle', $post->ID); ?>
<?php echo pegar_campo('banner', $post->ID); ?>
<?php echo pegar_campo('oquefazemos_0_imagem', $post->ID); ?>
<?php echo pegar_campo('oquefazemos_0_titulo', $post->ID); ?>
<?php echo pegar_campo('oquefazemos_0_resumo', $post->ID); ?>
<?php echo pegar_campo('oquefazemos_0_conteudo', $post->ID); ?>